# HomebrewでPython3をインストールするとpipが使えない

Tags: python, python3, macos, homebrew

macOSでHomebrewを使ってPythonを入れ直したのですが`pip3`コマンドでPython3のpipを呼びだそうとしたのですが`command not found`になってしまいます。

前にHomebrewを使ってPython3を入れた際は
インストールが終わると同時にpip3へのシンボリックリンクが作られていたため
すぐにpipを使いはじめることができていました。

どうすればpip3コマンドでpython3のpipを呼び出せるのでしょうか?
自分でln -sを実行しなければいけないのでしょうか?

python3.6.5
macOS 10.13.4

Comment: Homebrew の python は、2018年1月〜3月あたりに破壊的変更が[ありました](https://methane.hatenablog.jp/entry/2018/03/11/Homebrew_%E3%81%AE_Python_%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%89%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8C%E3%82%82%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E6%88%BB%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B)。現在の状況は公式サイトの[こちら](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Homebrew-and-Python.md#python-3x-or-python-2x)に書かれており、これによると 2018年5月現在 `brew install python` で `pip3` が入るはずです。`brew update` はしたか、`python3` コマンドは存在するか、などを教えて頂けませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自分で解決できました。
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)`
とした後に`brew install python`を実行したところ`/usr/local`に`pip3`のシンボリックリンクができていました。

/usr/localのownerがrootになっていたのではないかと思います。